# How to preform an action in a different folder with uses Github actions

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github-actions, zephyr-rtos

Trying to get Github actions working for a specific workflow involving Zephyr and West. Currently, I have West initializing via [this](https://github.com/zmkfirmware/zephyr-west-action) marketplace plug-in with the Docker version to save time. My Zephyr project runs on an nrf9160 chip and builds locally by running `west build -b nrf9160dk_sgnns` in the `project` folder.

For now, everything works up until the building part, which(I believe) has to call West in the `project` folder and not in the parent folder. However, how do I chain the events in this case? Currently, I call `West build` like this

```
  - name: West Build
        uses: 'docker://zmkfirmware/zephyr-west-action-arm:latest'
        id: west-build
        with:
          args: |
            'cd " project "'
            'build "-b nrf9160dk_sgnns"'
```

However, this results in an error if I do it like the action suggest the system can't find my board, thus how could I perform this build action in my `project` folder correctly?

I tried setting the `working-directory` however this results in the error `working-directory cannot be used with uses, with`

Comment: how is build without `cd project` and  with:
          ```command: 'build'
          command-args: '-b nrf9160dk_sgnns'```

Comment: do you really have a folder named " project " (with empty spaces before and after)?

Comment: When I used that the correct files are not present thus I get the error `No board named 'nrf9160dk_sgnns' found` due to the fact that the files are not initialized/present in the folder.

Comment: @Stefano No, I changed it but the error persists